# how to generate *.nps cpu snapshot from commandline

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

How to generate *.nps file cpu snapshot from commandline?
Can't find a clue from -help commandline or visualvm.github.io.
I know how to use it from ui, but need it triggered from monitoring tools.